# Why don't eggs from Pokestops appear in the Journal?

Tags: pokemon-go

The journal displays all the caught Pokemon and the items you get from Pokestops but in my case, it does not display the eggs I get.

Is it normal or is it a glitch?

Comment: Eggs hatching also doesn't appear too bad

Comment: did you just tap the pokestop stuff? beacause you have to tap it then drag it to ur journal

Comment: You don't need to tap the bubbles to actually collect the items, in fact you can tap the 'X' at the bottom of the screen to immediately collect them and return to the map/avatar screen, and I've never dragged anything into the journal.

Comment: @vynsane Also if you just sit there eventually the items will float to the top and collect automatically :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** The August 8th update has added hatches to the Journal.

<strike>It's not yet confirmed if eggs get added to the journal from Pokestops though, which I know your original question was asking about.</strike>

I tested just now - **eggs from Pokestops do *not* show up in Journal still**. Nice one, Niantic.

[image]

---

Nice catch!

Eggs from Pokestops **are** missing from the Journal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm chalking this up to a **bug**!

Comment: Got my +1 for the freehand ?

Comment: @clabacchio I try